# Need Help Creating Code to Query Multiple Tables and Return Rows Where the Sum Equals Query

Tags: mysql, pandas, python-2.7

I am trying to create a python script possibly using pandas that can query multiple tables to return rows from one or more of those tables where the sum of the returned rows equal the query. Any help, no matter how small, would be greatly appreciated!

Here is a rough example of a query:

```
Query: Select * where Apples ='Granny Smith' and Quantity ='10'
```

Results (Each Barrel is a different supplier, and has its own table):

```
Table  |Apple      |Quantity|Added to Barrel|Last Fulfillment
Barrel1|GrannySmith|5       |08/20/2019     |NULL
Barrel2|GrannySmith|4       |08/20/2019     |NULL
Barrel5|GrannySmith|1       |08/25/2019     |NULL
```

-In this example, Barrel3 & Barrel4 don't contain any GrannySmith, only Fiji.
Once the "order" for Granny Smith Apples are fulfilled, the last fulfillment column will be updated with a date, then the script will pick from the oldest Last Fulfillment line first.

Comment: 'Each Barrel is its own table' - I am not clear on your data structure - what is the naming convention for each barrel? AND are there a growing number of barrels? AND is there any limit on the number of barrels in theory or any restriction on those you wish to query?

Comment: 'Each Barrel is its own table' - that was your first mistake.

Comment: Are you specifically after combinations of 3 barrels, or are you after the fewest number of barrels required to make 10 Granny Smiths, or are you after any combination of barrels containing at least 10 Granny Smiths? Lots of clarification required.

Comment: I am trying to create script that will (continuing the apples scenario) pick apples from multiple barrels (B) to fill an order for apples. I already have the script to add to each B when I get a shipment in, and I must keep each B separate based on supplier. So, the script I need to create takes an incoming req for A and picks from each barrel to fill the order. For instance, I get a request for 10 Granny Smith Apples, and B1 has 5, B2 has 4, and B3 has 8. The script should return the rows from each B that adds up to the 10 being requested. The least # of B's to fill the order would be ideal.

Comment: I struggle with this concept. Supplier is really a synonym for barrel. Every time you get a delivery in from a supplier you up the quantity in the barrel for that supplier. When you take some apples out you always look in barrel 1 first followed by barrel 2 etc until you get n apples. doesn't that mean that barrel n will have rotting apples because you are not interested in stock age only in order fulfillment.

Comment: P.Salmon you are correct. The other part of this that I didn't speak about (just wanted to get a start on the script), is that the script will need to rotate the results. Meaning, if I pull from B1,B2,&B4 on fulfillment1, then on fulfillment2, I will need to pull from the supplier with the oldest fulfillment dates first.  I'm pretty sure I have that part figured out. I just need some bones of a script to build on.  Adding info to my example above now.